# Exclude a product in widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to hide all child categories to be displayed in widget from specific subcategories 1 & 3. Not found any solution.
 Woocommerce hide product of subcategories in dropdowns and widgets

Main Category 1 > Subcategory 1 > Child Category 1

Child Category 2 Subcategory 2 > Child Category 3 Child Category 4

Main Category 2 > Subcategory 3 > Child Category 5

Child Category 6 Subcategory 4 > Child Category 7 Child Category 8

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_widget_category' );

  function exclude_widget_category( $args ) {

// Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be excluded
$exclude_terms = array();

// Push the default term that you need to hide 
array_push( $exclude_terms, 80,81,82 );

// Find all the children of that term
$termchildren = get_term_children( 80,81,82, 'product_cat' );

// Iterate over the terms found and add it to the array which holds the IDs to exclude
foreach( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( '81', $child, 'product_cat' );     
    array_push( $exclude_terms, $term->term_id );
}
```

Comment: you have to add in your efforts to show what you have done so far to achieve the functionality.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Not clear